# RouteCollection GetVirtualPathForArea returns root or "/"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This only happens on one particular Controller Action

If I pass to the UrlHelper a controller of "Home" and an action of "Index", the virtual path gets returned as "/".  On all other controller actions, the virtual path is returned correctly.

I've used .NET Reflector, but it's only getting me so far.  What would cause the path to be returned as "/" and not "/home/foo" on only one controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a default MVC project, `/Home/Index` path is the same as `/` because it's set to be default. Changing the name of your `Home` controller or changing the default route, will show you that the problem is not in the controller, but your default route settings.

Comment: This was the problem.  I had a case that wasn't being caught in the RoutePaths and so was defaulting to "/".